# Excel VBA import data to existing Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I've found similar questions asked before, but I can't seem to figure it out using those examples.

I'm writing a macro in Excel where the last step needs to import all the data in Sheet1!A:Q (headers in row 1) to Table1 in an Access database. I need to make sure each column in Excel corresponds to the correct field in Access.

I am using Excel 2010/2013 and Access 2010/2013. Code I am currently using is:

```
Sub AccImport()

Dim acc As New Access.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\Database1.accdb"
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        acImport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        "Sheet1", _
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        True, _
        "A1:Q1000"         'Need to change to reflect the last row in the sheet
acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
acc.Quit
Set acc = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code results in error message, highlighting `acc As New Access.Application` and displaying "Compile error - User-defined type not defined"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried?  Have you gotten any errors?

Comment: I figure I need to use some of this syntax -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793%28v=office.14%29.aspx and perhaps code from here http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76110. If you can point me towards some code I think I feel comfortable adapting it, I just haven't found something I can adapt. @thunderblaster

Comment: I had tried this, but got an error:      `Dim acc As New Access.Application
    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\Database1.accdb"
    acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            acImport, _
            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            "tblExcelImport", _
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
            True, _
            "CallLog"
    acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acc.Quit
    Set acc = Nothing`

Comment: Can you edit your question and include that code and also describe the error you're getting (both the specific error number & message, and also the line it errors on)?  Your syntax looks correct, so it's hard to say what the problem is without the error details.

Comment: @thunderblaster added the code to the question. I'm still learning how to use stackoverflow properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: In the VBA Editor, go to Tools -> References.  Scroll down to "Microsoft Access 11.0 Object Library" (yours might not be 11.0, but you're looking for the one that says Microsoft Access) and ensure the box is checked.  If not, check it and click OK.  This solved the compile error when I tested it.

Comment: Thanks! I would have _never_ though of that or found that!

Answer (score 1):

Have you included references in VBA for Access?

```
Tools > references > Microsoft Access xx.x Object Library
```